# Is there a way to convert to a type from multiple other types in Rust?

Tags: rust

I'm in a situation where I'm frequently composing a struct from two other types:

```
struct Foo {
    a: usize,
    b: usize,
}

enum Bar {
    X,
    Y,
    Z,
}

struct Baz {
    bar: Bar,
    a: usize,
    b: usize,
}

impl Baz {
    fn new(bar: Bar, a: usize, b: usize) -> Self {
        Baz { bar, a, b }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let foo = Foo { a: 1, b: 2 };
    let bar = Bar::X;

    let baz = Baz::new(bar, foo.a, foo.b);
}
```

I would love to use something like the `From` trait here, but given that I'm pulling from two different types, I don't think it's possible. Is there a cleaner or more idiomatic way to accomplish this or should I just use a macro?

Comment: One way to do this is to use tuples and implement `From<(Foo, Bar)>` on `Baz`.

Comment: You could also just go with the struct literal syntax with containing the `Foo` as a property on `Baz` instead of the property dupe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As EvilTak proposed:

```
impl From<(Foo, Bar)> for Baz {
    fn from((Foo { a, b }, bar): (Foo, Bar)) -> Self {
        Baz { bar, a, b }
    }
}
```

Then, you can use it like:

```
let baz = Baz::from((foo, bar));
```